# How to store result of a AWS CLI command in Classic Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines, aws-cli, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-tasks

I have a AWS CLI task (create-upload) that when run, returns with a json result that contains an URL. This task works fine.

I however need to use the URL from that create-upload task in the next task (upload-file).

Inside that create-upload task there is a section titled "Output variables" but it has nothing in it. I'm not sure if I am supposed to enter a variable name in there to be used for storing the output, and then to be used in other tasks?

Note, this task is not written in BASH or YAML, it is a UI task (classic I believe it is called).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand at this point it is impossible to store the result/output of Classic UI task to a variable.

You have to use bash or something else where you have more control.